# c++ pointer issue - update pointer through method

Tags: c++, pointers

I am new to c++ programming. Playing around a bit with pointers. But i don't understand how the program given below printing 20 instead of 10.

According to me it should be 10! but it prints 20.

I want to get a clear concept in pointer but its getting harder a bit. It would be really helpful if anyone explain with details.

TIA

```
void fun(int *p) 
{ 
  int q = 10; 
  p = &q; 
}     

int main() 
{ 
  int r = 20; 
  int *p = &r; 
  fun(p); 
  printf("%d", *p); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You're passing the pointer by-value to the function. This pointer is copied into the function. You are then assigning to this pointer another value. Therefore, the value of p is the same before and after the function (luckily, in your case)/

Comment: You don't understand one of 2 things, I don't know which one. 1) `p = &q;` means that `p` now points to a different address, namely the address of `q`. The value in previous address of `p` doesn't change. 2) When you pass `p` to a function, you actually pass its copy. Therefore, the copy of `p` points to `q`, not the `p` from `main`.

Comment: `void fun(int *p) { int q = 10; *p = q }` When you pass a pointer (by value), the function receives a copy of the pointer holding the original memory address as its value. You must update the value at that address in `fun`, not assign a new pointer. (and of course, the pointer you pass cannot be a `nullptr` doing it this way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter pointer `p` is passed by value, then any modification on `p` itself (instead of the object pointed by `p`) has nothing to do with the argument pointer being passed.

You can make it pass-by-reference, e.g.

```
void fun(int *&p) 
{  
    p = new int(10); 
}
```

then

```
fun(p); 
delete p;
```

Or make it pass-by-pointer.

```
void fun(int **p) 
{  
    *p = new int(10); 
}
```

then

```
fun(&p); 
delete p;
```

PS: In your code you're trying to assign the pointer to the address of local variable `q`, which is destroyed when get out of the function, left the pointer danlged. After thant any deference on it (e.g. `*p`) leads to UB.

Answer (score 0):

@songyuanyao already answered, but just to help you understand, run this code and try to realize the difference:

```
void fun(int &p) 
{ 
  int q = 10; 
  p = q; 
}     

int main() 
{ 
  int r = 20; 
  int *p = &r; 
  fun(*p); 
  printf("%d", *p); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Here the output is 10, as you thought it would be. Can you figure out why?

Comment: is it because now inside fun() we are assigning new value into the memory address that pointer p was pointing to?

Comment: Think this way: if you set `int *p = &r`, `p` is a pointer to the real address and `*p` is an int. When you pass `*p` to `fun`, you are basically passing the address of `r` (and `fun` actually expects an address as argument). Then, you set the address `p` (and `r`) as the address of 10. When you leave the function, both `*p` and `r` will be 10.

Answer (score 0):

Going further (to better understand pointers) :)

```
void f(int *p) {
int q = 10;
*p = q;
```

}
This works too. What happens here? The p is the argument that is the copy of the original pointer.
But this argument contains address to original outer variable.
"*p" names dereference the pointer to access to value that addressed by it.
"*p = " means change the value by address that contains argument p.